# How can I pass the Hidden Field value in SqlCommand in C# asp.net Three Tier Architecture?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to insert,update,delete values in db using stored procedure in three tier architecture.For that I am using the HiddenField to perform the above action.In order to perform the insert operation,I have to pass the value `@Action='Insert'` to stored Procedure by SQL Command.But in my code,I cant view the hiddenfield Id.can anyone help me do so.
My code as,

```
public void WorkingProgress(Workin_Variable V1)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Action",HiddenfieldId.value)
     }
```

Here HiddenFieldId not shown

Comment: Is it a server side control?

Comment: please show your markup for hidden field??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `runat="server"` tag in your HiddenfieldId control. Also if you are not reading this in code behind file, read this in a variable and pass to `ADO.NET` function.

Answer (score 0):

Anything you want to access from back end you need to add runat="server" then you can pass
If its table or Paragraph tag.
For this senerio

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField" runat="server" value="" />
```

in back code access from `HiddenField.Value`